# discord py bot triggers twice on_member_update function

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm writing a discord bot in Python and have run into a rather stupid error I can't fix at the moment.
The Bot is supposed to supplement online pen and paper rpgs by allowing users to register nickname-based characters for which checks can be rolled etc.

If a player comes online the bot should check if that player is in the character database under it's owners key. If that's the case the bot should assign a specific role to the user, that allows further commands.
For persistance reasons a file is created on the server (aka my machine) for every registered character and one user can have multiple characters (because i play multiple campaigns with the same people simultaneously). You can see this is the first step in a long row of auto-assigning and revoking roles depending on online, offline, nicknames, etc.

I've only written the very basis of the code for this and ran into a problem that baffled me and that I can't seem to solve.

My Code:

```
# on_member_update the bot recognizes if someone comes online and their name shows up in the character database
# if so the bot should assign them the role "Spieler" on the server. Right now prints to console for testing.
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before,after):
    if before.status == discord.Status.offline and str(after) in characters:
        print("Rollenwechsel!")
    else:
        print("Studenten verteilen Flugblätter. Nichts geschieht.")
```

If I run this on my pc or my laptop it triggers twice on status changes and once on changes like nickname or role.

How do I stop the double triggering? Bonus question: Why does it do this?

Thanks in advance.

ps: If needed ask for more code.
pps: I'm quite new to coding. Keep that in mind.
ppps: If this has been answered anywhere else I apologize. I wrote this after about an hour of furious googling.

Comment: Code as posted triggers only once under both conditions for me. Do you have other events being processed? Maybe strip down your code to just this event and verify the double triggering?

Comment: Stripped it down to just this event. Still double triggers for me.

Answer (score 0):

The on member update fires for each guild the user is in. Its firing twice because your bot is in 2 servers and its detecting updates for the user in each server. Its the same user but not the same member.
It doesn't fire twice on nickname or role changes because those are specific to each guild.

You can use on user update to avoid this:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_user_update

Unfortunately though, unlike on_member_update, on_user_update doesn't check for status updates among some other things. But you can use this to check for nickname changes in a guild.